# Java naming conventions

Tags: java, variables, naming, naming-conventions

My full variable name is Unique Code, however I want this variable to be "ucode"-ish.

So what would be correct concidering Java naming conventions?

1. ucode
2. uCode
3. UCode

Comment: Whats the problem with full name `uniqueCode`?

Comment: If I'm a developer maintaining your code in a year's time, uniqueCode is much clearer than any of the variations above

Comment: I vote for uniqueCode, if I would see variable named uCode I wouldn't know what it means without digging into declaration. You should always write your code to be as easy to read as possible, which does not always mean shortest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [the coding conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367). For variables, camel case is recommended. Re. the naming, I would have thought

```
uniqueCode
```

would be the most logical choice (I'm aware that wasn't in your list of choices). Any `uCode` variant looks like an abbreviation of *unicode* to me, and I would regard it as misleading. The above isn't an excessively long name (it's not an [AbstractAnnotationAwareTransactionalTests](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/test/annotation/AbstractAnnotationAwareTransactionalTests.html), for example!)

I perhaps wouldn't embed the usage/restriction of the variable in the name itself. If you refactor the usage then you'll have to change the name of the variable too.

Comment: +1. Why use cryptic variable names when you can use readable ones too?

Comment: Well Brian. Given the choices I give you. What is the most fitting if you have to choose from them.

Comment: camelCase, but those restrictions seem counter-productive.

Comment: Is there some reason you're not telling us why variable names have to be limited to 5 characters?

Comment: @ZeDonDino, you shouldn't use any, what is your problem with using `unquieCode`?

Comment: also that's what IDEs are for: They do the typing of long names for you. Makes your code much easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Official doc for naming conventions:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367

Answer (score 2):

Variable names should start with a lowercase letter and every other word should begin with a capital letter. So `uCode` or `uniqueCode` would fit with this convention.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Answer (score 0):

I would always start my variables with a lowercase and then capitalise each word, so I would go with 2 but would prefer to call it `uniqueCode`.