# Java: how to get object instance from string?

Tags: java, android

Before we start, I should mention that I'm trying to do this in Android, though I believe it is not relevant to what I am trying to resolve in this question specifically.

I should also mention that I have seen similar things asked already, though they did not exactly help me in what I am trying to do. While some of them have helped me get a general idea of how it should be done, in the end, I've been left helpless by the too-specific problems the other users had.

I believe it would also be useful to clarify that I am relatively new to programming in Java, with very little experience or knowledge of complex data structures.

What I am trying to do is as follows:

Say I have a class named WordThing, which contains two strings, called name and color, and an int called picture (which is used for retrieving the ID for an imagebutton). I also have a separate char called uno, whose value is a. There is an instance of WordThing called a, with its values properly assigned. I want to ask if it'd be possible to call one of the values of WordThing a using the value of uno, like this:

```
getValue(uno).picture
```

While I am aware that the above example is, in many ways, incorrect, nevertheless am I asking whether such a thing would be possible.

To clarify, in reality there are more chars than just uno, namely four, all with different letters, who are subject to randomization. My intention is to use these random letters to call upon four distinct WordThing instances, whose values will then be used in altering some elements of a given View, like this:

```
upperleftButton.setImageResource(getValue(uno).picture);
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain issue in simple way

Comment: I think you're after a `HashMap<String,WordThing>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28computer_science%29), also know as an Associative Array or dictionary. Maps are used to store items in key/value pairs, where the key can be used to look up the value within a map. In java (and android) you can use a map like this.

```
Map<String, WordThing> wordThingMap = new HashMap<String, WordThing>();

// Add some items to the map
wordThingMap.put("a", new WordThing());
wordThingMap.put("b", new WordThing());

// Do some other stuff
someSuperSpecialMethod();

// Retrieve values from the map
WordThing a = map.get("a");
```

As a side note, you should probably think about re-naming some of your variables. WordThing isn't really that descriptive, and variable names like "a" and "b" will become very difficult to work with very quickly. For some tips on naming variables, [see this question for a start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089616/java-naming-conventions).

Comment: Thank you for the help. Don't worry, the names are purely hypothetical.